# Query to Snowflake database isn't working because no active warehouse is selected

Tags: python, r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm able to successfully connect to the Snowflake database via R but I'm having trouble getting the data because no active warehouse is selected. Below is the error message:

*No active warehouse selected in the current session. Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command.*

Here is my code I'm using.

```
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(
    odbc::odbc(), 
    UID    = user, 
    PWD    = pass, 
    Server = host,
    Warehouse = 'YOUR_WAREHOUSE_NAME',
    Driver = "SnowflakeDSIIDriver",
    Role = role,
    Database = database,
    Autthenticator = "external browser"
  )

dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE LIMIT 100")
```

I've based my connection and query from this thread on [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/query-data-from-snowflake-database/12937/3) but I'm not having any luck. I've also tried using the 'use warehouse MY_WAREHOUSE' command in my query without any luck.

Note: I can connect successfully and query data via Python so I think this is an R specific issue.

Comment: 1) Maybe your role has no privileges to use this warehouse. Are you sure you use the correct role? 2) If this is something about the R, have you tried to run "USE WAREHOUSE MY_WAREHOUSE" statement as a separate statement? What is the result of running this command (from R)?

Comment: 1) I'm using the same role as my Python connection. I also switched roles in R to check and I'm getting the same error. 2) I've also used that in my query as a separate statement. ```dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE LIMIT 10", "USE WAREHOUSE MY_WAREHOUSE")``` I get the following error _Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1617: 57P03: No active warehouse selected in the current session. Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse'_

Comment: some other ideas to try: 1) what happens if you use another warehouse? 2) could it be a name resolution issue with the casing of the warehouse name - so perhaps wrap your reference in "<wh_name>" if it is not defined as upper case 3) what happens if you ensure that the WH is started (resumed) before initiating the connection from R (rather than letting it try to auto-resume)

Comment: Hi Mike, I only have access to one warehouse (at least for now). I tried 2 but that didn't seem to work. Can you elaborate on #3 a little further? How would I start the WH before establishing the connection from R? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the only problem, but there's a misspelling in your code. "Autthenticator" should be "Authenticator". You should only need that parameter if you're using SSO.

Comment: Nice catch Greg. Unfortunately I only messed up the spelling on here. :(

Comment: Hi Trevin, I just mean make sure your warehouse is running (alter warehouse MY_WAREHOUSE resume;) and that it has been auto-suspended in case the connector is not able to resume it if it had been. Also have you tried running the query above in this order - dbGetQuery(con, "USE WAREHOUSE MY_WAREHOUSE", "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE LIMIT 10") - or those 2 queries as 2 separate items (the use warehouse one executed first)? Also just wondering if there is logging you can turn on in R to see what's happening on the Snowflake connection side - and is there anything more in the Snowflake query history?

Comment: Hey Mike, I figured out how to connect. See my comment below. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this issue too. It's probably not the best answer as I'm just testing some dev code (in python), but I had to issue:

```
GRANT USAGE ON WAREHOUSE my_warehouse TO ROLE writer_role;
```

Of which the user I was using to connect to Snowflake is a member of, then I was able to write to the table.

Comment: I'm returning after almost 4 years (time flies) and a Snowflake certificate.  It's clear why you would need to issue this command. Any SELECT operation would require a virtual warehouse (compute) to run. That's the part Snowflake will charge you for, so if you don't have the USAGE permission on a virtual warehouse, you can't run any queries.

Answer (score 0):

1. Seems like an R bug IMHO if the python equivalent code is fine
2. Your role can have a default warehouse assigned, perhaps it is blank and requires it need be specified upon connection; and a bug in the R code is stopping it from being set?

Comment: Okay, so after a good night of sleep I figured out how to connect to the proper datatables. RStudio was saving my old Snowflake connection strings so whenever I would make a change it wouldn't effect the connection. So I deleted any connection string and used the correct one. Also, there seems to be an issue when I use a password and the authenticator. When I only use the authenticator it's okay. But when I use both I can't connect correctly. (My user email and user ID are two different email. That may effect it.)  The good news is I can now connect. Thanks!